Statistical methods to compare 21 theoretical values to experiments
I am testing a theoretical model to compute an entity called the g-shift of diatomic molecules (the g-shift for a given diatomic molecule is expressed as a simple scalar value).
I have calculated the g-shifts for 21 different molecules for which I also have the g-shifts determined from experiments.
I would like to compare the theoretical model to experiments, and I am wondering which statistical methods would be ideal for this purpose. 
I guess one obvious choice would be the Mean Absolute Deviation and/or RMSE. Visually, I could show a scatter plot together with a perfect agreement line that represents the perfect agreement between theoretical and experimental values.
Would someone suggest other methods to determine how well the theoretical method agrees with experiments?

Questions about ways to analyse a specific dataset are better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ . If you expect perfect agreement, than your visual analysis corresponds to testing the hypothesis that $a = 0 \wedge b = 1$ in a linear regression of the form $y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma), \mu_i = a + bx_i$ where $x_i$ are the theoretical predictions while $y_i$ are the observed results.
